# Помогите найти МЭШ OS

Tags: ос

Во всех современных школах установлена новая операционная система. Я хочу установить такою же себе на виртуалку, но не могу найти её. Единственное что смог откопать это инструкция: https://school.mos.ru/help/instructions/m-os/features-mos/mos-pc/ Помогите найти саму операционку.

Comment: кеды как кеды...

Comment: будешь на месте посмотри файлы `/etc/os-release` `/etc/apt/sources.list` `/etc/yum.repos`

Comment: это Linux с KDE в качестве графической оболочки. Выбираете люьой понравившийся дистрибутив: OpenSUSE (по дефолту с KDE), Kubuntu, Manjaro, KDE Neon...  Если нужен наш родной, то Alt Linux или ROSA

Comment: https://hub.mos.ru/mos/iso

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут можно скачать образы оси - https://wiki.dno-it.ru/2023/04/24/ssylki-dlya-skachivaniya-obrazov/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/876616)

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут все актуальные версии - https://hub.mos.ru/groups/mos/-/packages

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]